# Why does "small" give an error about "char"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Trying to compile an open source project with both VS2010, VS2012 in x86 and x86_64 on a windows platform running QT5.4.

A file named *unit.h* contains a part :

```
[...]
// DO NOT change noscale's value. Lots of assumptions are made based on this
// value, both in the code and (more importantly) in the database.
enum unitScale
{
   noScale = -1,
   extrasmall = 0,
   small = 1, // Line that causes errors.
   medium = 2,
   large = 3,
   extralarge = 4,
   huge = 5,
   without = 1000
};
[...]
```

Generates

- error C2062: type 'char' unexpected
- error C3805: 'type': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ','

I tried every trick in my hat to solve it. I removed every use of the "small" enum in the code and I still get the error. But after having removed all the uses, I rename "small" to "smallo" everything is fine. It seems to indicate name collision but a file search gives me no references in the whole project. It's not any keyword I know of.

Got any ideas?

EDIT: Thanks to very helpful comments here is an even stranger version **that works**. Could somebody explain?

```
#ifdef small // Same with just straight "#if"
#pragma message("yes")
#endif
#ifndef small
#pragma message("no") // Always prints no.
#endif

#undef small
enum unitScale
{
   noScale = -1,
   extrasmall = 0,
   small = 1,
   medium = 2,
   large = 3,
   extralarge = 4,
   huge = 5,
   without = 1000
};
```

EDIT 2: The pragma directive was showing yes but only in files that had previously loaded the windows.h header, and it was lost in the compiler output in a sea of no.
Thanks everyone! What a quest.

Comment: Did someone define a `small` macro? If so, please kick them in the nuts.

Comment: yes. definitly `small` is defined before. put `#undef small` before your enum.

Comment: Run your file through the preprocessor (with GCC that'd be the -E option, not sure how with MSVC).  See where `small` first appears.

Comment: try to use F12 (intellisense) to see if it can jump to the definition of `small`. otherwise, also try with `#if defined(small)` while you're at it. I dont see why the ifdef section fails.

Comment: @JohnZwink Running the preprocessor is often a good choice. But if ''small'' defined with  a macro you won't find it in the preprocessed output. :-( But you can succeed if it's defined by a typedef.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`small` is a defined in `rpcndr.h`. It is used as datatype for [MIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367314(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: We have a winner! The inclusion of windows.h -> winscard.h -> wtypes.h -> rpcndr.h -> which states `#define small char`.

Comment: This has caused great pain to many developers.

Comment: upvote if you have encountered the pain!